# EntityFrameworkCore - Classes and Entity distinction

Tags: migration, entity-framework-core, entity

Just been writing up my models and dbcontext using a code first approach for EFCore and i've hit a small problem... specifically with classes and generating migrations.

It seems with entityframework any class is seen as an entity/table (my assumptions so far) but what if I want a class to be a list of fields extended onto my entity?
For example:

```c#
public class Person {   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address AddressDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

How can I mark the address class as additional fields to the person entity as opposed to a separate entity?

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks